# Tesseract returning None instead of number

Tags: python-3.x, python-tesseract

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqUvb.png)

When I run `pytesseract.image_to_string('file.png')`, the function is returning None instead of

> '4X 35'

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very low contrast image, so you have to enhance it with PIL (or another library) before Tesseract can convert it properly. I've found that cropping as close to the text as possible also helps, though manually tweaking the pixels for the crop is not very scalable if you have a lot of different image sizes.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance

im = Image.open(r'file.png').convert('L') # convert to grayscale
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)
im = enhancer.enhance(15.0)

# crop 7 pixels off top and 10 off bottom
im = im.crop((0, 7, im.size[0], im.size[1] - 10)) 

# convert with whitelist of capital letters and digits
result = image_to_string(im, 
    config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'))

print(result) # 4X35
```

Comment: @MaheshBabu it worked like a charm for me. Did you try with that exact code?

Comment: And the same small image you linked to in your post?

Comment: Yes. I have used the same image with the provided code.

Answer (score -1):

Use pillow to open the image and then pass the pillow object to pytesseract.

Example-

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
im = Image.open("file.png").convert('L')
im2 = im.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius = 1))
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(im2)
```

covert('L') converts the image to grayscale, you can also apply Blur to soften the image

Comment: I am still getting None as output. I have attached the image above. If you don't mind, can you please check if you are able get text output?